# Доступ к конкретной ячейке GridView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Собственно есть GridView и ArrayAdapter:

```
GridView gvTabl;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.tvText, data);
    gvTabl = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvTabl);
    gvTabl.setAdapter(adapter);
    adjustGridView();
}
```

Можно ли в этом случае как-то изменить 2-ую и 3-ю ячейки GridView.
Изменить - убрать текст и сделать другой фон.

Comment: Как изменить? Вообще через кастомный адаптер сделать это не проблема, а через системный - геморой

Comment: "Изменить - убрать текст и сделать другой фон." Добавил текст. Так и знал, что придется разбираться в этих адаптерах непонятных. Спасибо за ответ.